# How to set static IP for 2 network interfaces in systemd linux

Tags: systemd, network-interface, yocto

I have a Yocto distro that uses `systemd` (like ArchLinux) to allow static IP configuration via `/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network` file.

I need to set a static IP for 2 network interfaces (`eth0` & `eth1`) though and cannot seem to do this by specifying it in `20-wired.network` file. I also tried setting it in `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` and `/etc/systemd/network/eth1/network` files respectively but this does not work either.

`20-wired.network` works fine for setting a *single* interface.

Any guidance on how to specify 2 interfaces greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just added another file besides 20-wired.network (that contains eth0 static IP) and called it 30-wired.network and added eth1 related settings in there.